# CodeDeploy is not replacing my active tasks although my replacement tasks are healthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-code-deploy, blue-green-deployment

I am trying to do blue-green deployment on ECS. I am not sure why my tasks are not being replaced by Code deploy and why it is showing this error "The deployment timed out while waiting for the replacement task set to become healthy. This time out period is 60 minutes."

Although my replacement tasks are healthy. I have attached my screenshots showing all. Please anyone can tell me which thing is causing this problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Events (Edited to add events)

```
15018c8f-3da3-43cd-b152-2c6b5dd7676a
2020-04-30 17:05:01 +0500
service generalapplication updated computedDesiredCount for taskSet ecs-svc/9240344397483279222 to 0.

9d3bc64a-7033-4331-91a5-4e632ea6e4f3
2020-04-30 16:05:05 +0500
(service generalapplication, taskSet ecs-svc/9240344397483279222) has started 2 tasks: task d5cd8467-21aa-44c2-b18f-3655bb5da9d8 task 49846a86-586b-4c82-9e51-5058a3532d97.

d80257ed-1cfd-4f2a-994f-5f23d5460a4a
2020-04-30 16:05:05 +0500
service generalapplication updated computedDesiredCount for taskSet ecs-svc/9240344397483279222 to 2.


7ce215bf-2731-4490-b185-67b8055ce733
2020-04-30 15:59:47 +0500
service generalapplication has reached a steady state.


a69b722e-3137-4b0b-b81f-886da84edf3f
2020-04-30 15:59:47 +0500
(service generalapplication, taskSet ecs-svc/2005228967178810525) updated state to STEADY_STATE.


f285cabd-b442-4801-9d1d-3c2aa2ee9a47
2020-04-30 15:56:02 +0500
(service generalapplication, taskSet ecs-svc/2005228967178810525) has started 1 tasks: task e67abc5d-38ac-4945-9f0f-e95edc735885.
ed6a1486-933c-4fda-88c2-b8b541832cc4
2020-04-30 15:55:51 +0500
(service generalapplication, taskSet ecs-svc/2005228967178810525) has stopped 1 running tasks: task 246f29ed-c426-4385-ab11-d3db87d7b5b2.
cf5940b3-cfe9-4431-99ed-c8beda9b3f7d
2020-04-30 15:55:51 +0500
(service generalapplication, taskSet ecs-svc/2005228967178810525) (port 8080) is unhealthy in target-group Production-ECS-Cluster-BlueTG due to (reason Target is in an Availability Zone that is not enabled for the load balancer).
238cbba0-99be-4a65-b33e-d20783aa1c37
2020-04-30 15:55:51 +0500
(service generalapplication, taskSet ecs-svc/9552322035717332169) updated state to STEADY_STATE.
bd42844a-1f28-4b61-b0d9-df5d828dd132
2020-04-30 15:55:51 +0500
service generalapplication updated computedDesiredCount for taskSet ecs-svc/9552322035717332169 to 0.
432410af-8df4-4003-ad6d-19888534ed2f
2020-04-30 14:55:57 +0500
service generalapplication failed to launch a task with (error ECS was unable to assume the role 'arn:aws:iam::359761372359:role/ecs-task-role-for-springboot' that was provided for this task. Please verify that the role being passed has the proper trust relationship and permissions and that your IAM user has permissions to pass this role.).
6c63d84e-de51-464a-adac-696960875f45
2020-04-30 14:55:56 +0500
(service generalapplication, taskSet ecs-svc/7257951011749426554) updated state to STEADY_STATE.
a89ed108-13c5-412d-a83e-55c9f45561af
2020-04-30 14:55:56 +0500
service generalapplication updated computedDesiredCount for taskSet ecs-svc/9552322035717332169 to 2.
6e602645-c6f2-4054-a351-5924de143801
2020-04-30 14:55:56 +0500
service generalapplication updated computedDesiredCount for taskSet ecs-svc/7257951011749426554 to 0.
c3973e16-33ad-4a95-9ef2-b8dadefb1af7
2020-04-30 14:37:20 +0500
service generalapplication failed to launch a task with (error ECS was unable to assume the role 'arn:aws:iam::359761372359:role/ecs-task-role-for-springboot' that was provided for this task. Please verify that the role being passed has the proper trust relationship and permissions and that your IAM user has permissions to pass this role.).
3dcdb5dd-c5a5-4700-9a5a-eacc0606372a
2020-04-30 14:37:19 +0500
service generalapplication updated computedDesiredCount for taskSet ecs-svc/7257951011749426554 to 2.
411d17bb-8d69-4a51-b507-e6f160d24eb5
2020-04-30 14:35:41 +0500
(service generalapplication, taskSet ecs-svc/2005228967178810525) has started 2 tasks: task 246f29ed-c426-4385-ab11-d3db87d7b5b2 task 5101ffa1-01e5-4984-9d0e-beb7250e3dc3.
```

Comment: Can you show how your 2 TGs are setup? Since you have two different ports (80 and 8080), guess you use two listeners as well? Also can you go to ecs->cluster->service and check on events. What does it say there?

Comment: what is your current timeout period?

Comment: @Marcin Yes I am using two listeners as well. With one TG I have attached one listener that listens to port 80 same thing for other one which listens on port 8080.. I have added events to the question description. There are three events that correspond to replacement tasks.

Comment: The events write: " is unhealthy in target-group Production-ECS-Cluster-BlueTG due to (reason Target is in an **Availability Zone that is not enabled for the load balancer"**

Comment: @BhatasanaPrashant its 60 minutes. Can we change this timeout from UI?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Its so silly of me. Let me try by enabling AZ for load balancer

Comment: Just curious if it worked out?

Comment: Yeah it worked. (y)

Comment: You can add the answer to the question, I will mark it as accepted